# SMTP Live.com "Failure sending mail"

Tags: c#, email, smtp, send

What is wrong with these Code? Alltimes it throws an Exception  "{"Failure sending mail."}"! And i dont know why. Please help me.

Edit : Inner Exception : {"Unable to connect to the remote server"}

```
        string smtpAddress = "smtp.live.com";
        int portNumber = 587;
        bool enableSSL = true;

        string emailFrom = "myemail@live.com";
        string password = "myPassword";
        string emailTo = "otherEmail@live.com";
        string subject = "Hello";
        string body = "Hello, I'm just writing this to say Hi!";

        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
        {
            mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom);
            mail.To.Add(emailTo);
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = false;

            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
            {
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFrom, password);
                smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
                smtp.Send(mail);
            }
        }
```

Comment: check if there is inner exception with more info

Comment: Inner Exception : {"Unable to connect to the remote server"}
Internet works.

Comment: {"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond myIPAdresse"}

Comment: Something not related with your code...Firewall? Try to telnet.

Comment: check this
http://forums.asp.net/t/1211112.aspx?A+connection+attempt+failed+because+the+connected+party+did+not+properly+respond+after+a+period+of+time+or+established+connection+failed+because+connected+host+has+failed+to+respond

Answer (score -1):

Remove using  keyword when send the mail like this:

from:

```
using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
```

to:

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
```

Remove braces also like this:

```
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFrom, password);
smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Same Error: Unable to connect to server!